# Can time crystals scatter incoming waves toward the past?

Tags: time-reversal-symmetry, braggs-law, time-crystals

Can [time crystals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_crystal) scatter incoming waves toward the past? I think it is a fair question to ask, albeit the answer is overwhelmingly likely NO. But since the concept is fairly new, I'm wondering if there could be on the horizon an experimental setup aiming a beam toward one of these time crystals and establish the presence or absence of a time-backward Bragg reflection